# Display checkbox values in HTML after select, submit and email results from process.php

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox, selection

I have a checklist that's broken down into days, stage, timeShow, and bandName. I am displaying the options from a database with this script and I'm trying to display the results (and eventually email them) to the user on the 'process' page. How do I carry over the $result_x to the following page? 
Here's an example of one of the 'blocks' for Saturday, Stage 1 and the value of the selection is the 'ID' of the row.

UPDATE- Part one is solved. Now looking to get the results sent to an email address input by the user.

FORM SOLUTION- 'Selection.php'

```
        $sql_Sat1 = "SELECT * FROM bandSched WHERE day='saturday' AND stage='stage 1'"; 
    mysql_query($sql_Sat1); 
    $result_Sat1 = mysql_query($sql_Sat1);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_Sat1))
            {
                echo "<ul><li>";
    echo'<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'.$row['id'].' " id="bandSched_' . $row['id'] . '" />';
    echo '<label for="bandSched_' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['timeShow']." ".$row['bandName'] . '</label>'; 
    echo "</li></ul>";

            }
```

SOLUTION- 'process.php'

```
        if ( ! empty($_POST['id']))
    { foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) { $_POST['id'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$key]); } 
    $in = implode(', ', $_POST['id']); 
    $sql_Sat2 = "SELECT * FROM bandSched WHERE id IN ($in) ORDER BY FIELD(id, $in)"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql_Sat2) or die('MySQL Error ' . mysql_errno() . ': ' . mysql_error()); 
    }
     if ( ! isset($result))
    {
    echo 'You did not select anything';
    }
    else
    {
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['timeShow'] ."</td><td>" . $row['bandName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    }
```

Comment: Use sessions to save data so it can be accessed across multiple pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrying data from page to page can either be done with Sessions, Cookies, or posting hidden form elements containing the data.

Comment: I've done this before with straight html/javascript. Now I'm using mysql to populate the options w/ checkboxes, I'm not sure how to include a hidden input along with it...

Comment: If the user is just viewing and can't change the status of the checkboxes I would suggest not using a checkbox. Simply display the data to the user with text and then instead of checkboxes use hidden form elements to carry the data to the next page (change your checkboxes to type hidden). Checkboxes imply action by the user.

Comment: The user is selecting the checkbox next to the bands they want to see.

Comment: Oh ok. I think I understand your question now. The name of each checkbox should be descriptive and unique. Then when the user submits the form boxes that are checked will have the value stored in $_POST['name_of_field']. Use print_r($_POST) or var_dump($_POST) to see the structure of the POST array after the form is submitted.

Comment: I'm using this:                                                               echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['id'] .' "name=""' . $row['id'] .'  />';    //and it shows the info correctly on the main page, but still getting the fetch array error

Comment: var_dump($_POST) gives me: array(1) { ["id"]=> NULL }  // I'm not sure what that means-- looking it up!

Comment: A couple things. [my_sql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns a numeric array. Use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to get an array with column names for keys. Also when you call [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) use it along the lines of mysql_query('...') or die('MySQL Error' . mysql_errno() . ': ' . mysql_error());

Comment: We can move this over to chat if you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11478/discussion-between-j-money-and-commandrea)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have the attribute checked="checked" in your <input type="checkbox" />, the value will not be sent with the form data.

Try this:

```
 echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['id'] .'"name="selected" checked="checked" />';
```

Does this solve the problem?

Comment: When I tried this, it automatically checked every box next to the options on the first page. Cool, but I think you meant something else as that's not necessary- but I see what you're saying. I have to pass that it's checked somehow. As I'm using php/mysql to output the option rows (bands/times) how do I also insert the post- which led me to the sessions attempt above. I was trying to figure out how to include a 'hidden' input selection along w/ an checkbox input type...oof.

Comment: Ok, I was trying too hard to think outside of the box on this. Do you have everything working at this point?

Comment: Hi Matthew- j.Money stayed w/ me last night in chat until I resolved this- we didn't use sessions- I'll be back in a bit to update the question and reflect an answer- thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sessions provide you the data, but you still need to make a valid query.  The only thing that sessions do are store data on the server.  They do not keep any of the program execution, variables, etc.

Your error message is telling you that mysql_fetch_array was not supplied a MYSQL result resource (and it wasn't you supplied it an integer of the id value).  The query will not be remembered across the session.

Also, mysql_* is deprecated, use PDO or mysqli.